# How to get CSS property value from HTML <object> using generalistic JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

EDITED:

I now have tried this:

```
var google, finalObject;

function getpositionx() {

    google = document.getElementById('google');
    finalObject = window.getComputedStyle(google);
    return parseFloat(finalObject.style.left);

};

getpositionx();
```

There isn't a syntax error now, but I get this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined

**Why is this happening?**

*(The JSFiddle link below is updated with this new problem)*

---

I'm trying to get and set the size and the position of an external SVG using JavaScript. I'll have to do this for up to 6 different objects, so I want one single function to get (or set) the value I need for whatever object I'm working on. I've made a sample code to show what I'm trying to do - you can check it out on JSFiddle (link below). Here I have the JavaScript, wich is invalid because of the function that should get the values. How can I do this without having a different function for each object?

JavaScript:

```
var google;

function getelement() {

    google = document.getElementById('google');

};

function this.getpositionx() {

    return parseFloat(this.style.left);

};
```

I've also tried to do this:

```
function getpositionx(objectid) {

    return parseFloat(objectid.style.left);

};
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/barcellosm/fpss64m2/15/)

Thank you for you attention :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `window.getComputedStyle` the method directly return the style attribute calculated of your object. you can access directly the css attribute in the rreturn object.

So to solve your issue you should use :

```
var google, finalObject;

function getpositionx() {

    google = document.getElementById('google');
    finalObjectStyle = window.getComputedStyle(google);
    return parseFloat(finalObjectStyle.left);

};

getpositionx();
```